# What does a 'reservation' for an iPhone 6 at the online Apple Store mean?

Tags: apple-store, iphone

My order for an upgrade-elegible iPhone 6 at the online Apple Store was interrupted by Apple with a "reservation" for a phone, confirmed by an e-mail with a number identifying my reservation and a link where I could check on the status of my reservation.

At the time I made my reservation, wait times for delivery were a few days, and are now much longer, and getting even longer. The reservation expires 24-hours after it was made, though it appears to be making no progress: the status, when it can be found (which is about 1 try out of 5) indicates still waiting to "reach the carrier systems", even though I can now order an upgrade-eligible phone on the same number from the Apple Store without a reservation.

Does my "reservation" actually hold a phone that was available for delivery at the time I made it (that is, available in a few days), or is it just a way of saying "come back later"?

Comment: What precicely were you selecting for a delivery option? An iPhone for direct delivery to you or an iPhone for pick up at a retail store? The latter has always used "reservation" for the terminology. Also, do you have an actual order number or just a cart with an order in progress?

Comment: @bmike: Direct delivery. Apple sent a 12-character "reservation number" I can use (when it works) to check status. The mail they sent reads Your iPhone has been reserved and your reservation number is: B201EO5PMZU1

*"We will email when we’re able to reach the carrier systems. The email will include instructions to complete your order as well as the return link. You will have 24 hours from the time the email is sent to return to the Apple Online store to proceed with your order. If you do not complete your purchase within 24 hours, your reservation will be canceled."*

Comment: Excellent. I would call the toll free number for the apple online store where you purchased to make sure you still have a reservation. If there is a delay in the carrier approval, I'm sure Apple will honor the reservation - especially if you contact them and ask to provide payment now to ensure the transaction doesn't get cancelled.